# Protractor Tests in Mac Giving Error - result was not received in 10 seconds

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

Our CI runs protractor tests on Mac machine (Chrome browser). The script is hosted in a test machine which triggers the suite to run on a remote Mac. The Mac runs a selenium server which handles selenium requests. Off late, some of the tests have been failing with error **`'unknown error: result was not received in 10 seconds'`**. This has come up only recently. Tests work fine on Windows and iOS.

Details of the error:

> Failures:
>   Message:
>   [31m    Failed: unknown error: result was not received in 10 seconds
>   (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
>   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 20.12 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
>       System info: host: 'lab-imac.local', ip: '10.70.210.97', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_65'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/sc/9n_x6lvs7mb0cvx22znsy86w0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.tVh2Ny},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=46.0.2490.80, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: 13bd640cff1fe4c6ca2083526cf92579[0m
>       Stack:
>       UnknownError: unknown error: result was not received in 10 seconds
>         (Session info: chrome=46.0.2490.80)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322455 (ae8db840dac8d0c453355d3d922c91adfb61df8f),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 20.12 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.45.0', revision: '5017cb8', time: '2015-02-26 23:59:50'
>       System info: host: 'lab-imac.local', ip: '10.70.210.97', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.1', java.version:
>   '1.8.0_65'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>       Capabilities [{applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, mobileEmulationEnabled=false,
>   chrome={userDataDir=/var/folders/sc/9n_x6lvs7mb0cvx22znsy86w0000gn/T/.org.chromium.Chromium.tVh2Ny},
>   takesHeapSnapshot=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true,
>   version=46.0.2490.80, platform=MAC, browserConnectionEnabled=false,
>   nativeEvents=true, acceptSslCerts=true, locationContextEnabled=true,
>   webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true,
>   javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
>       Session ID: 13bd640cff1fe4c6ca2083526cf92579
>           at new bot.Error (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\error.js:108:18)
>           at Object.bot.response.checkResponse (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\atoms\response.js:109:9)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver\webdriver.js:379:20
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
>       From: Task: 
>           at PromiseFactory._promiseFactoryFunc (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:73:25)
>           at PromiseFactory.makePromise (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.utils\src\PromiseFactory.js:36:25)
>           at Object.ViewportSize.setViewportSize (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\ViewportSize.js:118:31)
>           at Eyes.setViewportSize (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:333:29)
>           at Eyes. (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.sdk\src\EyesBase.js:704:32)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:75:17
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
>       From: Task: 
>           at PromiseFactory._promiseFactoryFunc (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:73:25)
>           at PromiseFactory.makePromise (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.utils\src\PromiseFactory.js:36:25)
>           at EyesBase.startSession (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.sdk\src\EyesBase.js:693:37)
>           at Eyes. (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.sdk\src\EyesBase.js:595:25)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:75:17
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
>       From: Task: 
>           at PromiseFactory._promiseFactoryFunc (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:73:25)
>           at PromiseFactory.makePromise (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.utils\src\PromiseFactory.js:36:25)
>           at EyesBase.checkWindow (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\node_modules\eyes.sdk\src\EyesBase.js:580:37)
>           at callCheckWindowBase (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:179:47)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:198:20
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
>       From: Task: 
>           at Eyes.checkWindow (D:\Users\Administrator\node_modules\eyes.protractor\src\Eyes.js:197:27)
>           at Object. (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\Elements\specs\Test\test-spec.js:52:14)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:96:23
>           at new wrappedCtr (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\base.js:2468:26)
>           at controlFlowExecute (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:82:18)
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>           at process._tickCallback (node.js:368:9)
>       From: Task: Run it("load page") in control flow
>           at Object. (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:81:14)
>           at attemptAsync (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1819:24)
>           at QueueRunner.run (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1774:9)
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1801:16
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1745:9
>           at D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasminewd2\index.js:18:5
>           at goog.async.run.processWorkQueue (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\goog\async\run.js:124:15)
>       From asynchronous test: 
>       Error
>           at Suite. (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\Elements\specs\Test\test-spec.js:47:5)
>           at addSpecsToSuite (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:743:25)
>           at Env.describe (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:713:7)
>           at jasmineInterface.describe (D:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:3219:18)
>           at Object. (D:\Users\Administrator\CI\Perforce\verification\Elements\specs\Test\test-spec.js:18:1)